# Mysql join acting weird

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a very simple query but I am a beginner at this and I couldn't understand really what the problem is as it's not working properly in second case:

```
SELECT a.user_name, a.password, a.id, r.role_name
FROM accounts as a 
JOIN roles as r ON  a.role=r.id
```

[image: result of the first query]

```
SELECT accounts.user_name, accounts.password, accounts.id, roles.role_name 
FROM accounts
JOIN roles ON accounts.role=roles.id
```

[image: result of the second query]

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts as a 
JOIN roles as r ON  a.role=r.id
```

[image: result of the third query]

`accounts.role` and `roles.id` linked with foreign key. I try to select everything using `*` in the third query but it didn't even get anything from second table only got everything from first table(as in the last photo). So what might be the problem ?

Comment: Could you share your attempt with `*` and the result you got? You mentioned it in the question, but didn't share it.

Comment: The two queries are the same, except for the use of table aliases.  They should be producing the same results.  I also don't understand which works and which doesn't -- which is the "first" and which is the "second"?

Comment: @Mureinik sorry guys  I rushed little bit and made some mistakes. Updated with the results and the last query. I said first and second respectively as I put in to the page.

Comment: So you want to show all data from first table and second table with a single _select_?

Comment: Actually I want to select a few but also I tried to select all to detect the problem

Comment: I think you have to use _alias_ like ´a.*´ and ´r.*´. Because using only _*_ means you are selecting only data _from_ main table, which is accounts

Comment: Yeah make sense, but how about the first two ? Why its not working when I use long form like accounts.user_name ?

Comment: @HalilTutkun. Sorry my bad. Using only * does show all data from all tables, you are including.

Comment: Hi. You don't explain what any of the queries should be returning, and yoru queries are wrong. So how can we know what you want? (Rhetorical.) Edit your question to be clear & give a [mcve]. That includes using text (possibly code and/or tables) for text, not using images/links. Comments are not for clarifications. PS PKs, FKs & other constraints are not needed to query. What matters is what a row means when it is in a table (base or query result). Read what join does & look at many examples. Join returns *all combinations* of rows, on/where keep some rows & select keeps some columns.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour has no sense, all fields must to appear when you use `*`

Let's do a test on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a903/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t1 ( i int, a char);
insert into t1 values (1,'a');
create table t2 ( i int, b char);
insert into t2 values (1,'a');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from t1 inner join t2 on t1.i = t2.i
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a903/3/0)**:

```
| i | a | i | b |
|---|---|---|---|
| 1 | a | 1 | a |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select *
from t1 x inner join t2 y on x.i = y.i
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a903/3/1)**:

```
| i | a | i | b |
|---|---|---|---|
| 1 | a | 1 | a |
```

You can see all times all fields appear. May be is a issue with the program you use to connect and make the queries. Check for twice you are executing all the sentence, not only the firsts 2 lines, also check if they are a scroll bar to see more data.

Comment: Ok I'll try to reset my data base and if I can spot the problem I'll let you all know. I think problem might be about foreign key between accounts.role and roles.id. Thanks for now.

Answer (score 0):

I've restarted the database with given codes:

```
$mysqli->query('
CREATE TABLE `crm`.`roles` 
(
    `id` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
    `role_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `edit` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,   
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
);') or die($mysqli->error);


$mysqli->query('
CREATE TABLE `crm`.`accounts` 
(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `role` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `user_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     `last_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,   
    `hash` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `active` BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,   
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`role`) REFERENCES roles(`id`)
);') or die($mysqli->error);
```

and every combination of SELECT is working fine now. I don't know what the problem was since I don't remember making any changes on the tables.